# Ensuring a specific solution between two moduli

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let *a, b, m, n* for:
$x\equiv a\pmod m$
$x\equiv b\pmod n$
satisfy the Chinese Remainder Theorem.
Let *a, m* be constant.

Since the Chinese Remainder Theorem can be applied, there exists a solution *x*. Consider that $x\equiv b\pmod n$ represents the set $[..., b - 2n, b - n, b, b + n, b + 2n, b + kn, ...]$. If $b+kn\equiv a\pmod m$ for any for any given *b, n*, is it rigorous enough to suggest $b+kn$ is a always a solution?

Comment: For *all* integers $b,n$, then if $b + kn \equiv b \pmod n$ is always true.  If, for some given $b,n$, it's also the case that $b + kn \equiv a \pmod m$, then $x = b + kn$ for those given $b,n$ values would be a solution to the system of $x \equiv a \pmod m$ and $x \equiv b \pmod n$. I'm not quite sure what you mean by asking if it's "rigorous enough"? Are you asking about if there's a specific method which should be used instead, requiring knowing what these values of $b,n$ are, the uniqueness, or something else?

Comment: I am wondering if I'm missing something to be certain $b + kn$ is always a solution.  Alternative solutions are welcomed.

Comment: $b+kn$ is only a solution if it equals a number of form $a+jm$ if not coprime modulus,  use lcm instead of product. etc.